# Get All Combinations of N-Length For Different Sized Input Lists

Tags: python, combinations

I have seen other questions on using `itertools` to generate combinations from a single list & even a list of lists, but I am looking for something slightly different.

I have a list of lists of differing lengths (some are 2-attributes long, some are 4-attributes long). I need to be able to generate all combinations of lists that contain all elements from any of the lists that ADD up to 6 final elements total.

Here is my source data -

```
A = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"]
B = ["B1", "B2"]
C = ["C1", "C2"]
D = ["D1", "D2"]
E = ["E1", "E2"]

all = [A,B,C,D,E]
```

My ideal (sample) output would be -

```
[A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2]
[A1, A2, A3, A4, C1, C2]
[A1, A2, A3, A4, D1, D2]
[A1, A2, A3, A4, E1, E2]
[B1, B2, C1, C2, D1, D2]
[B1, B2, C1, C2, E1, E2]
...
```

Is there a utility in `itertools` that would allow me to do this or would I need to write a custom loop to achieve this and if so what would be the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to combine a few of the tools from itertools to accomplish this but you'll also need a few loops to make things work.

To spell things out in pseudocode first, you want to:

1. Generate all combinations of all possible lengths (itertools.combinations + for loop)
2. Concatenate those combinations (itertools.chain)
3. Filter those combinations to only contain lists of length 6

The direct translation of that to code is:

```py
ALL_LISTS = [A, B, C, D, E]

LENGTH_6_CHAINS = []
for combination_length in range(2, len(ALL_LISTS)):
    for combination in itertools.combinations(ALL_LISTS, combination_length):
        chain = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(combination))
        if len(chain) == 6:
            LENGTH_6_CHAINS.append(chain)
```

If you want it to be reusable or to work with different possible output lengths, you might consider a generator helper function:

```py
def build_chains(item_lists):
    for combination_length in range(2, len(item_lists)):
        for combination in itertools.combinations(item_lists, combination_length):
            yield list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(combination))

LENGTH_6_CHAINS = [chain for chain in build_chains(ALL_LISTS) if len(chain) == 6]
```